# How to select value from list using JavaScript in html

Tags: javascript, html

this is code

```
 <c:forEach items="${names}" var="jk">
        <a href="openmessage" onclick="sendtoanother();" >
                <a1>${jk.read}</a1>
                <az3>${jk.idnum}</az3>
        </a>
     </c:forEach>
```

---

javascript for selecting the value and showing in alert box

```
   var df = document.getElementsByTagName('az3');
   var de = document.getElementsByTagName('a1');
                function sendtoanother() {
                    alert(df+" "+de); }
```

Comment: Please also use the correct tags - doesn't look like you want jquery here

Comment: can you describe more accurately what you need to be done, and if the code you posted does the job for you?

Comment: yes it does the job thanks to @panther he should half way and i figured it .

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection.

The first element of this tagname in page has an index `0`.

```
var df = document.getElementsByTagName('az3')[0];
var de = document.getElementsByTagName('a1')[0];
```

In `df` and `de` are HTML elements. You want their `.innerHTML`, I suppose.

Comment: is there anyone to help me with this problem plz got stuck

Comment: @MohdSaifFarooqui: Choose from _native_ HTML tags and use classes instead of creating _own_ `az3` and `a1` tags. `.getElementsByTagName` for unknown elements work just in a part of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

first get the index value from the list that is by using Jquery click function

```
        var ty;
              $(function hj() {
                  $('a').click(function () {
                       ty = $(this).index();
                       alert("this is " + ty);
                       kill(ty);
                    });
                });
```

then by passing the variable to another function and with using java script

```
function kill( tyo) {
   var de = document.getElementsByTagName('klw')[tyo].innerHTML;
   var df=document.getElementsByTagName('az3')[tyo].innerHTML;
                    alert("hi " + de);
                };
```